# facebook 502 nginx + fpm

Tags: facebook, nginx, php

I'm unable to post any pictures or other media in facebook. I have used the debuger (`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug`) and I always get:

```
Scrape Information
Response Code:  502
```

I use nginx 1.2.0 with php-fpm with sock not port (9000) 
My errror log does not show any error. The access log

```
69.171.237.14 - - [23/Mar/2013:19:00:29 +0100] "GET /video/X1KAW64412WH1OO/5123 HTTP/1.1" 200 11715 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"
```

Currently I have disabled the IPtables. php.ini and most of the timeouts are set to 3600

nginx.conf part:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /home/blabla/www;
       # fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/blabla/blabla/$fastcgi_script_name;
       # fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI      $request_uri;
        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
            access_log  logs/access._php.log  main;
 fastcgi_send_timeout  5m;
 fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
 fastcgi_connect_timeout 5m; }
```

I have tested using cloudflare services and it works great, but when I only point to my  server it stop. It happen to all my other websites located to this machine so it must be webserver configuration prolem I guess. I use centos x64

Comment: 1) Try `<?php header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"')`  2) Check if 502 is not generated by FB (some users reported it today)  3) If proxy or upstream server and FB doesnt talk the same protocol, 502 will show up too.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue.

My nginx logs indicated that a 200 response was being served, and requests in the browser showed a 200 response. Facebook was insistent that it was a 502 error.

It turns out that '502' can mean either 'Your server returned a 502' *or* 'I ran into a difficulty parsing the response'.

In my case, I had a non-compliant HTTP header (it conained a single question mark), which was causing Facebook to reject the response as being invalid. Removing this header fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook by default use ipv6 address if available To Solve this problem you have to enable iPv6 in a Ningx config file for each virtual host (if many sites hosted) to listen Any IPv6 address at port 80.
This will solve the issue with Facebook opengraph.